# Side-by-side caption positions of figure and table

Tags: r, figure, caption, quarto

In Quarto, it is possible to display a figure and a table side by side with `layout-ncol`. Theoretically, we should be able to use `cap-location: "bottom"` to set all captions to bottom, but it is not the case here. Is there a way to set all captions to bottom, including when using both table and figure?

Minimal example:

````
---
title: "sidebyside"
format: pdf
editor: visual
---

```{r}
#| layout-ncol: 2
#| layout-valign: bottom
#| cap-location: bottom
#| fig-cap: "A plot"
#| tbl-cap: "A table"

library(knitr)

# plot on the left
plot(cars)

# table on the right
kable(head(cars))
```
````

Output:

[image]

The expected output would have both captions in the bottom and no additional "A plot".

Comment: I think this has something to do with latex: There is a rule in text layout that captions for tables must be placed on top.

Comment: Yes. I think this is linked too. But I especially specified the caption location to be in bottom, and it does not seem to be taken into account.

Comment: (quarto dev here) This is a quarto bug. I created a [github issue](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/1267) to track. Thank you for spotting this!

Comment: Update - it seems that kable itself doesn't currently have support for caption positions: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1995.

Answer (score 5):

(quarto dev here) The only way to make this work presently is to set the caption location *document-wide* in the front matter. Our documentation is currently misleading wrt this, we will be fixing it very soon.

So, what you want is:

````
---
title: "sidebyside"
format: 
  pdf:
    cap-location: bottom
editor: visual
---

```{r}
#| layout-ncol: 2
#| layout-valign: bottom
#| fig-cap: "A plot"
#| tbl-cap: "A table"

library(knitr)

# plot on the left
plot(cars)

# table on the right
kable(head(cars))
```
````

This doesn't fix the multiple-captions "A plot" problem, though. That's a different bug. (The path of mixing figure and table captions is clearly not well exercised enough; we'll fix that too!)